# Integer number is too large or long number is too large

Tags: java

Hi I'm having trouble understanding why this isn't working

```
public class TeacherDemo {

    String name,gender;
    int phone;

        TeacherDemo teacher1 = new TeacherDemo();

        teacher1.name = "KM Tareq Mahmud";
        teacher1.gender = "Male";
        teacher1.phone = 01748714117;
```

when i run the  code there showing the error : java: integer number too large.

so how can i get input in phone number using integer or long number?? i also tried in long variable btw the same error happen , there showing long number too large.

Comment: Using a number type means that you will lose leading zeros in the phone number. If that is really what you want then consider class [java.math.BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Comment: Don't store phone numbers as ints. The leading zero is important; and an integer literal starting with zero is interpreted as octal. Store them as strings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is recommended that to store phone number one should use a string.

Edited:

```
   (1) adding + in number ex: +91 XXXXXXXXXX can break the code

   (2) adding 0 as a prefix makes it octal
```

So preferred to use String for number

Comment: Adding a 0 in front of a number in java means something different. So saying that he should try a different type of number does not help at all. Please just propose a solution when you are familiar with that language

Answer (score 7):

To save a bigger integer than `231 - 1`, use type `long` and write it like `01748714117L` **but** , to keep the leading `0` and as you don't really need it to be a numerical type (you won't use numerical operation on it) I'd suggest you save it as a `String`

```
// In declaration
String phone;

// in assignement
teacher1.phone = "01748714117";
```

Comment: Thank all,  i already change variable int to string and its working.

Comment: @devil-Dot you can think about accepting the answer so , the green tick

Answer (score 3):

## Octal

An `int` literal with leading zero (`0`) means [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) numbers. Your number has an 8, so the error shows its too large, not fitting an octal.

For storing a constant like telephone number, I suggest using [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html). For arithmetic, I suggest using [`BigDecimal`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=java%20bigdecimal%20java%2011&t=osx&ia=web).

Answer (score -2):

Try removing the first two lines of code.
maybe then it will work.

If it still doesnt work, show me the code for the TeacherDemo class.